# How to stop a self hosted Kestrel application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have the canonical code to self host an asp.net mvc application, inside a task:

```
            Task hostingtask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hosting ffoqsi");
                IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseApplicationInsights()
                    .Build();

                host.Run();
            }, canceltoken);
```

When I cancel this task, an ObjectDisposedException throws. How can I gracefully shut down the host?

Comment: Which platform do you target? When you target linux/macos (not sure later one) you can use linux SIGTERM to send a termination signal to the application

Comment: Seems on Windows you can use WM_Close though

Comment: I am on Windows, .Net Framework.

Comment: Did it work? I've never used it, but I know that Kestrel (or the Webhost) reacts on signals sent form the OS for graceful shutdowns. That's what the `IApplicationLifetime` mentioned below is for, to register to the cancellation token and perform cleanup work when the signal was received

Comment: thx for your input. i did not yet did into that solution. I expected a simple method call on IWebHorst or so. Currently I accept the exception and just dont care about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the most obvious way to cancel Kestrel. Run has an overload accepting a cancellation Token.

```
  public static class WebHostExtensions
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a web application and block the calling thread until host shutdown.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="host">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost" /> to run.</param>
    public static void Run(this IWebHost host);
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a web application and block the calling thread until token is triggered or shutdown is triggered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="host">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost" /> to run.</param>
    /// <param name="token">The token to trigger shutdown.</param>
    public static void RunAsync(this IWebHost host, CancellationToken token);
  }
```

So passing the cancellation token to

```
host.Run(ct);
```

solves it.

Comment: Ok, interesting.

Comment: Seems like this is no longer valid in asp.net core 2 ?

Comment: Hmm, cannot comment on this atm. is the overload gone?

Comment: It's been [moved](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1354) to the `RunAsync` method

Comment: Except that you can't call RunAsync from Main in .NET core.

Comment: I *can* call RunAsync in Main in .Net core.

Answer (score 6):

You could send a request to your web server that would call a controller action that, via the injected `IApplicationLifetime`, would call a `StopApplication()`. Would it work for you?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime

Comment: hmm, that sounds a bit contrived to me. But IApplicationLifetime looks like the right direction.